# Can I use MultiKeyMap to map key that is not a specific character

Tags: java

I am trying to write logic that will consume 2 `Strings` and compute `MessageCategoryCodeEnum`:

- MessageCategory
- Result

The logic is as follows:

[image]

I created code that handles only equals cases of `Result`, but I do not know how to handle NOT EQUALS cases from the table.

```
public class MessageCategory {

    public static MultiKeyMap<String, MessageCategoryCodeEnum> messageCategoryMap = new MultiKeyMap<String, MessageCategoryCodeEnum>();
    static {
        messageCategoryMap.put("Eligibility", "F", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.FATAL);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Validation", "F", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Eligibility", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Validation", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Documentation", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Servicer Guidance", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Observation", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a `Map`, you should use `if` statements.

Comment: Also, note that `Map.put()` only takes 2 arguments but you are passing 3 here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it can take multiple keys: put(K key1, K key2, V value)
 You can read documentation here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html

Comment: I missed that you are using `MultiKeyMap`. I am not familiar with this. I still think that the most straightfoward way to implement this logic is with `if` statements rather than with a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't really a way to implement a "not" in map that I know of... you can add for each category a default value, and then in case a result isn't found in the map, go to the default

```java
public class MessageCategory {

    private static MultiKeyMap<String, MessageCategoryCodeEnum> messageCategoryMap = new MultiKeyMap<String, MessageCategoryCodeEnum>();
    // Let's say '*' is the default state
    private static final String defaultResult = "*";

    static {
        messageCategoryMap.put("Eligibility", "F", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.FATAL);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Validation", "F", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Eligibility", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Validation", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Documentation", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Servicer Guidance", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);
        messageCategoryMap.put("Observation", "U", MessageCategoryCodeEnum.WARNING);

        // Set default value
        messageCategoryMap.put("Eligibility", defaultResult, MessageCategoryCodeEnum.INFORMATION);
    }

    public static MessageCategoryCodeEnum getCodeEnum(String cat, String result) {
        if (messageCategoryMap.containsKey(cat, result) {
             return messageCategoryMap.get(cat, result);
        } else {
             return messageCategoryMap.get(cat, defaultResult);
        }
    }
}
```